# Query against federated table loses connection?

Tags: mysql

Mysql 5.6 on Debian 9: I have a very large table on a server, serverA, and I have defined a connection from my database on serverB to the database on serverA, using `create server connA ...`, and I have defined a table on serverB that connects via connA to the very large table.

When I query the federated table on serverB, it work fine, if the query processes quickly on serverA:

```
# on serverB:
mysql> select * from game_action where game_action_id=4;
+----------------+---------+---------+------------------+-------+--------+----------+---------------------+
| game_action_id | game_id | user_id | game_instance_id | type  | amount | currency | created_timestamp   |
+----------------+---------+---------+------------------+-------+--------+----------+---------------------+
|              4 |    1096 |       1 |                4 | WAGER |   1.00 | GBP      | 2017-09-06 14:37:15 |
+----------------+---------+---------+------------------+-------+--------+----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.40 sec)
```

But (still on serverB):

```
mysql> select count(*) from game_action;
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

The table is very large, so it isn't surprising that it takes long to process, but I need to be able to do things that take long. We have had trouble with connections dropping due to timeouts in the past, and they have been very difficult to troubleshoot; changing different timeouts in my.cnf didn't help.

What is the best practice for troubleshooting this particular problem?

***Edit***

The very strange thing, I feel, is that there doesn't seem to be any timeout variables that match what I see - I set up a mysql instance just to test this:

```
$ # On serverB:
$ time mysql -u root -pAtauseq01 gameiom -e "select count(*) from game_action;"
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 1: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

real    9m23.275s
user    0m0.014s
sys     0m0.004s
```

So, about 9 min timeout, if it is a timeout. But on the remote server (serverA):

```
mysql> show variables like "%timeout%";
+-------------------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name                       | Value    |
+-------------------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout                     | 10       |
| delayed_insert_timeout              | 300      |
| have_statement_timeout              | YES      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout         | 1        |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout            | 50       |
| innodb_print_lock_wait_timeout_info | OFF      |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout          | OFF      |
| interactive_timeout                 | 28800    |
| lock_wait_timeout                   | 31536000 |
| net_read_timeout                    | 30       |
| net_write_timeout                   | 60       |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout              | 31536000 |
| slave_net_timeout                   | 3600     |
| thread_pool_idle_timeout            | 60       |
| wait_timeout                        | 28800    |
+-------------------------------------+----------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

***Edit 2***

ServerA:

```
mysql> show variables like "flush%";
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| flush         | OFF   |
| flush_time    | 0     |
+---------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

ServerB:

```
mysql> show variables like "flush%";
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| flush         | OFF   |
| flush_time    | 0     |
+---------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

***Edit 3***

On serverA:

```
mysql> pager grep -v PARTITION
PAGER set to 'grep -v PARTITION'
mysql> show create table game_action\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: game_action
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `game_action` (
  `game_action_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `game_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `game_instance_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(18,2) NOT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `created_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`game_action_id`,`created_timestamp`),
  KEY `GA_IX01` (`game_id`),
  KEY `GA_IX02` (`user_id`),
  KEY `GA_IX03` (`game_instance_id`),
  KEY `game_action_created_timestamp` (`created_timestamp`),
  KEY `ga_id_cur_tstmp` (`game_id`,`currency`,`created_timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1064199804 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

On serverB:

```
mysql> show create table game_action\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: game_action
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `game_action` (
  `game_action_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `game_id` int NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int NOT NULL,
  `game_instance_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(18,2) NOT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `created_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`game_action_id`,`created_timestamp`),
  KEY `GA_IX01` (`game_id`),
  KEY `GA_IX02` (`user_id`),
  KEY `GA_IX03` (`game_instance_id`),
  KEY `game_action_created_timestamp` (`created_timestamp`),
  KEY `ga_id_cur_tstmp` (`game_id`,`currency`,`created_timestamp`)
) ENGINE=FEDERATED DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci CONNECTION='gameiom'
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will from MySQL Command Prompt, SET GLOBAL NET_READ_TIMEOUT=3600; on Server A and Server B, it could be long enough to push all 1 million rows of data to Server B from the table.

Observations, A) The two SHOW CREATE TABLES have some significant differences in CHARSET and COLLATE strategy.  Not sure how significant this is, but it could be major.

Next URL is to FEDERATED engine detail document by Baron Schwartz from years ago.  He has documented many in depth details of how he tested in the early days of the engine availability.
https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2007/01/29/mysqls-federated-storage-engine-part-1/
and
https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2007/01/31/mysqls-federated-storage-engine-part-2/

Next URL is for lost connection possible resolution from MySQL - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-lost-connection.html